# is there any method to prevent delete of record which has child in sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

> is there any method to prevent delete of record which has child in
>   sonata admin?

Admin Controller file : SectionAdminController.php

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('subjectArea.subject',null, array('label'=>'Subject', 'route' => ['name'=>'list']))
         ->add('subjectArea',null, array('label'=>'Subject Area', 'route' => ['name'=>'list']))
          ->add('title',null, array('label'=>'Subject Section', 'route' => ['name'=>'list']))

      //  ->add('title')
        //->add('shortCode')
        //->add('description')
        ->add('published')
      //  ->add('publicationDate')
      //  ->add('releaseDate')
     //   ->add('expiryDate')
       // ->add('tsCreated')
        //->add('id')
        ->add('_action', null, array(
            'actions' => array(
              //  'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

**Suppose we have 3 tables like : A, x, y.**
**A** is the parent of x and y tables. There is many records in **x** and **y** tables which have foreign id of **A** table, so whenever we go to delete any record in **A** table (which have children in another tables), then it should be prevent to delete the record from **A** table.

Comment: I am not want to use override deleteAction function there

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite deleteAction in your admin controller. there is no other option for same.

Comment: There should be any another option to do this except deleteAction, Because I can't do this way in 50+ admin files